# Netbeans, xampp and Android Studio Silent install

Tags: command-line, bash, xampp, netbeans, android-studio

is there any way to make `Netbeans 8.1` `Xampp` and `Android Studio` to install via script without any GUI and user interaction?(All three of them got GUI installs.)